# Java application using Spring Framework failing to start on WebSphere 9.0.0.4

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I have a Java application that fails to start in IBM WebSphere 9.0.0.4.  Spring Framework startup begins but gets stuck indefinitely.  Turning on logging reveals it is continually loading Spring-managed beans (possibly in an infinite loop).  Stripping the application down to a minimal Spring application context with almost nothing in it starts up successfully.

The target environment it has been failing in is running Linux kernel 2.6.32-696.30.1.el6.x86_64 and IBM J9 version VM pxa6480sr4fp6-20170518_02 (SR4 FP6).  However, our test environment is running Linux 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs and IBM j9 VM 8.0.5.17 - pxa6480sr5fp17-20180627_01(SR5 FP17).

Some key dependency versions:

- Spring Framework 4.1.6
- Oracle JDBC 12.1.0.2.0
- MyBatis 3.4.1

We have the same problem with Spring Framework 4.3.18.

This application functions normally in Apache Tomcat 7.0, 8.5, and 9.0.

---

Here is a list of the jar files we include (some of these have version numbers in the name, some don’t):

- XmlSchema-1.4.5.jar
- activation-1.1.jar
- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- aopalliance-1.0.jar
- asm-5.0.4.jar
- aspectjrt-1.8.5.jar
- aspectjweaver-1.8.5.jar
- backport-util-concurrent.jar
- batik-anim.jar
- batik-awt-util.jar
- batik-bridge.jar
- batik-codec.jar
- batik-css.jar
- batik-dom.jar
- batik-ext.jar
- batik-extension.jar
- batik-gui-util.jar
- batik-gvt.jar
- batik-parser.jar
- batik-script.jar
- batik-svg-dom.jar
- batik-svggen.jar
- batik-swing.jar
- batik-transcoder.jar
- batik-util.jar
- batik-xml.jar
- cfgatewayadapter.jar
- cglib-3.2.2.jar
- classmate-1.3.1.jar
- commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
- commons-betwixt-0.8.jar
- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
- commons-digester-1.8.jar
- commons-discovery-0.4.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- commons-lang3-3.5.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- commons-pool-1.4.jar
- commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
- concurrent.jar
- flex-messaging-common.jar
- flex-messaging-core.jar
- flex-messaging-opt.jar
- flex-messaging-proxy.jar
- flex-messaging-remoting.jar
- flex-rds-server.jar
- geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.1.1.jar
- geronimo-jaxws_2.1_spec-1.0.jar
- geronimo-ws-metadata_2.0_spec-1.1.2.jar
- gson-2.3.1.jar
- guava-21.0.jar
- hibernate-core-4.2.4.Final.jar
- hibernate-validator-5.1.3.Final.jar
- hibernate-validator-annotation-processor-5.1.3.Final.jar
- httpclient-4.5.3.jar
- httpcore-4.4.6.jar
- ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.4.jar
- inflector-0.7.0.jar
- jackson-annotations-2.8.1.jar
- jackson-core-2.8.1.jar
- jackson-databind-2.8.1.jar
- javax.mail-1.5.5.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.2.jar
- jaxen-1.1.1.jar
- jboss-logging-3.2.1.Final.jar
- jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
- jdbc-stdext-2.0.jar
- jdom-1.1.jar
- jms.jar
- jsoup-1.8.3.jar
- jul-to-slf4j-1.7.12.jar
- lib.txt
- log4j-1.2.15.jar
- mybatis-3.4.1.jar
- mybatis-spring-1.3.0.jar
- neethi-2.0.4.jar
- ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0.jar
- opencsv-2.3.jar
- orai18n-12.1.0.2.0.jar
- org.springframework.flex-1.0.0.M2b.jar
- oro-2.0.8.jar
- pdfbox-1.7.0.jar
- saaj-api-1.3.jar
- saaj-impl-1.3.2.jar
- sdoapi.jar
- sdoutl.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.7.12.jar
- spring-aop-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-aspects-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-core-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-expression-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-jdbc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-modules-validation-0.8.1.jar
- spring-orm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-oxm-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-tx-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-web-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- spring-webmvc-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar
- stax2-api-3.1.1.jar
- swagger-annotations-1.5.9.jar
- validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
- velocity-1.6.2.jar
- velocity-tools-generic-1.4.jar
- walend-somnifugi.jar
- woodstox-core-asl-4.2.0.jar
- wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar
- xalan-2.6.0.jar
- xalan.jar
- xbean-spring-2.8.jar
- xdb6.jar
- xerces_2_5_0.jar
- xfire-aegis-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-annotations-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-core-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-java5-1.2.6.jar
- xfire-jsr181-api-1.0-M1.jar
- xfire-spring-1.2.6.jar
- xml-apis-ext.jar
- xml-apis.jar

Comment: What classloader policy do you have configured in WAS? You should use PARENT_LAST.

Comment: After solving this problem, consider updating all your libraries, unless you work for equifax. Some libraries are very outdated, e.g. pdfbox and log4j.

Comment: Probably would be helpful for responders to be able to see the Spring startup logging. At least excerpts that show the start & end of each repetition, including evidence of the same bean being instantiated more than once. But also maybe the entirety of the log, hosted somewhere & linked to from here.

Comment: From what I know about websphere, it doesn't come with/allow hibernate as persistence provider. In case you want to use hibernate you probably need other type of configuration on your server.

Reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ro/SSAW57_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tejb_configpp.html